# KDEnlive: shaking/shivering video after rendering to file

Tags: video, kdenlive

When I look at my project in the project monitor, it looks fine, but as soon as I render to file and watch it there, the image seems to be jumping up and down by a pixel or two very rapidly. It can be seen very clearly on text and is very annoying.

I rendered to MPEG-4/MP3. What can I change so this does not appear?

Here's an example from my video: https://streamable.com/0rj9m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the videos were completely fine, but the [Video player (Totem)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Videos) that comes with Gnome makes every video jump like this! I downloaded VLC player and the videos are completely ok.